# title not showing up, every time I connect the source and delegate the program would crash and when I don't connect them it doesn't print anything

Tags: swift, xcode

I created a program/game(with a navigation bar) where you go through the pages and on one of the pages there is a simple table view controller that I am just trying to print some sentences out and when I try to do so the titles don't show up, and if I connect the delegate and data view source it crashes, though when I don't connect them nothing shows up on the table

Everything explained up top

```
import UIKit

class VocabListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    let vocabWords = ["1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return vocabWords.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = vocabWords[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the crash log? Have you registered a cell with the reuse identifier called "cell".

Answer (score 0):

**Always** reuse cells

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = vocabWords[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

If the code crashes you made a design mistake for example an identifier mismatch.